# Displaying MongoDB data in HTML table is adding blank rows

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, web-scraping, html-table, cheerio

The mongoDB data I am displaying is information i scraped from a website using cheerio. I scrape the data, save it into a mongo collection (called `Store`), and then display that information in an HTML table using ejs.

**Problem:**

The first table displays information just fine, with 26 rows of data. The second table, however, displays 26 blank rows and then 25 rows of the data i scraped. Sometimes the roles will be reversed, just depending on which scrape occurs first, so I know it has something to do with when it gets put into the db.

Can someone please explain how I can fix this?

**Code:**

scrape function (function is exactly the same for second set of data but instead of SUP, it says QA):

```js
var scrapeSUP = function() {
  var SUPStoreInfo = [];
  return Axios.get("http://example.com").then(function(response){
    var $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    $('.row > tbody > tr:contains("SUP")').each(function(i, element){
      let SUPResult = {
        "environment.SUP": $(element).children().next(),
        "store.SUP": $(element).children().next().next(),
        "version.SUP": $(element).children().next().next().next()
      };
      SUPStoreInfo.push(SUPResult);
      //make sure Store collection is empty
      Store.count({}, function(err, count){
        if (count === 0) {
            //if empty, add newly scraped data
            Store.create(SUPResult, function(err, new){
              if (err){
                console.log(err);
              }
            });
        } else {
            //if Store collection is not empty (has old data), remove all contents
            Store.remove({}, function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    //once all contents removed, add newly scraped data
                    Store.create(SUPResult, function(err, new){
                      if (err){
                        console.log(err);
                      }
                    });
                }
            })
        }
     });
    });
    return SUPStoreInfo;
  });
}
```

please let me know if you need to see other code (html tables, mongoose schema, etc)

Comment: In `$(this).children().next()` did you mean to be using `$(this)` and not `$(element)`?

Comment: @Joe sorry yes, meant to say ```$(element)```, i've fixed it in the code

Comment: If I'm reading that code correctly, it uses cheerio to scrape the HTML, finds all table rows that contain "SUP", and for each row pulls the first 3 fields into an object, pushes the object onto an array, and then deletes everything in the store and add just the last row.  So when this is all done, SUBStoreInfo contains an array of data from all of the rows, but the Store collection contains only the data from the last row.  Is that correct?